# Exchange 2007 and PSTs

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook

I have approximately 5000 users and many have PST files that they have used for archiving.  I'm now in a scenario where I need to import those PSTs back into their Exchange Mailbox.  We are running Exchange 2007 with Outlook 2010/2013.  I was researching Microsoft Exchange PST Capture 1.0/2.0 but cant find any place that definitively says Yes this will work or No it wont work with Exchange 2007.  Does anyone know the answer to this, or does anyone have a good solution to this?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: Unfortunately, "product placement" / service recommendation is off here. But search for PST Tools, with 5000 Users I would especially aim for an Enterprise ready tool, which PST Capture is definitely not.

Comment: I don't understand the dilemma. You can import the PST file into the mailbox from Outlook or from the EMS using the Import-Mailbox command.

Comment: Kinda hard for 5000 Users. You have to discover them, you have to centralize them, you have to find out ownership, you have to handle exceptions, failed items, failed ingestions... It will take years manually

Comment: I don't see it as being that difficult. You can find examples on importing PST file en masses at these links: http://www.knowthenetwork.com/2009/07/using-powershell-to-import-multiple-pst-files-into-exchange-2007/ - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691363(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: I am in the migration business. Trust me... for big corporations, it's a nightmare to do it

Comment: @joeqwerty my main dilemma is out of my 5k users i don't know who has a pst and those that do, how many psts they have.  MichaelZ is correct in saying it could take a very long time to do this manually and there is a good possibility of missing someone.  I'm looking for a tried and true methodology to doing this, where its scripting or purchasing a tool.